# Making social network icons horizontal

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficult making my social icons horizontal. I thought floating them left would do the trick or making the element an inline-block. I'm stuck so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
 <!-- Social network icons -->
 <div id="social">
 <ul class="soclist">
 <li><a class="youtube" href="img/youtube-logo.png" target="_blank" title="youtube"></a></li>
 <li><a class="twitter" href="img/twitter-logo.png" target="_blank" title="twitter"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Social Sidebar */

ul.soclist li {
display: inline-block
}

#social {
position: fixed;
top: 2px;
right: 73px;
width: 43px;
display: block;
}


a.youtube {
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
background: url(../img/youtube-logo.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
}



 a.twitter {
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
background: url(../img/twitter-logo.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "width: 43px;" from #social.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed the width and it's still vertical.

Comment: Thank you, Drawrdesign! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `display:block` from `a`:

```
a.youtube {
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
background: url(../img/youtube-logo.png) no-repeat;
/*display:block;*/
}



 a.twitter {
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
background: url(../img/twitter-logo.png) no-repeat;
/*display:block;*/
 }
```

[here is an example inlining your links](http://jsfiddle.net/LLS9e/) (without images )

Comment: I tried that earlier and it removes both icons. I'm stumped. Thank you for the suggestion.